# Add record to table only if data has changed since last record by date

Tags: mysql, date, merge

I need help trying to find a efficient method of adding data into a table only if the data has  changed.

I have the first table which is **LatestResults** and only stores the latest results ( 1 for each team number)

```
TeamNumber(Primary) TeamScore TeamWorkUnits RecordDateTime
1 - 500 - 600 - 2012-09-22 08:20:00
2 - 400 - 6 - 2012-09-22 08:20:00
3 - 90 - 15 - 2012-09-22 08:20:00
4 - 1 - 0 - 2012-09-22 08:20:00
```

The other table which is called **HistoricResults** stores a copy of very result in case I need it for statistics in the future.

```
HisotryKey(Auto-Primary) TeamNumber TeamScore TeamWorkUnits RecordDateTime
1 - 1 500 - 600 - 2012-09-22 08:20:00
2 - 2 -400 - 6 - 2012-09-22 08:20:00
3 - 3- 90 - 15 - 2012-09-22 08:20:00
4 - 4 - 1 - 0 - 2012-09-22 08:20:00
5 - 1 490 - 600 - 2012-09-21 08:20:00
6 - 2 -300 - 6 - 2012-09-21 08:20:00
7 - 3- 40 - 15 - 2012-09-21 08:20:00
8 - 4 - 0 - 0 - 2012-09-21 08:20:00
```

So I want to merge the first table into the second only if the data TeamScore or TeamWorkUnits has changed since the last record by RecordDateTime.

Meaning if TeamScore and TeamWorkUnits are the same you keep the oldest entry in the History table.

I would by far prefer do this totally within MySQL for speed if possible.

Currently I need to check about 100,000 records per hour

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm not a MySQL expert, but why not have it in a single table? Wouldn't that be simpler?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/. SO doesn't work this way. Show us some code/error/effort and we would help you solve it.

Comment: Ok, sorry I thought this was a site to help those without the knowledge / skill. I will look else where if people do not wish to help those like me here.

Comment: Hi Svish, Thanks for the formatting I did not see how to do that when I posted. As to why the 2 tables, it is simply because I am getting 100,000 records an hour so the HISTORY table will grow to be very large. I will mostly only need the latest data which is why that LATEST table is kept small and quick to query.

Comment: Can't that be solved with indexes and views?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
insert into HistoricResults 
  (teamNumber, TeamScore, TeamWorkUnits, RecordDateTime)
  select
    lr.teamNumber, 
    lr.TeamScore, 
    lr.TeamWorkUnits,
    NOW()
  from
    LatestResults lr
  where 
    exists (
      select 
        *
      from
        HistoricResults hs
      where
        hs.teamNumber = lr.teamNumber and
        (hs.TeamScore != lr.TeamScore or hs.TeamWorkUnits != lr.TeamWorkUnits)
        and hs.RecordDateTime = (select max(RecordDateTime) 
                                 from HistoricResults hs1 
                                 where hs1.teamNumber = lr.teamNumber)
      order by RecordDateTime desc
    )
```

Here is how it should works: subquery within `exist` is looking in `HistoricResults` for the most recent records with `TeamScore` or `TeamWorkUnits` different from `LatestResults` table record. If such record is found, then external `select` selects appropriate records from `LatestResults` and such records are finally inserted into `HistoricResults`.